# What are Mystic Coins used for? (And what are  Zommoros's favorite trades?)

Tags: guild-wars-2

Completing the Daily Guild Wars 2 Achievement earns some experience, coin, a chance at a black lion consumable, and a single Mystic Coin.

The monthly achievement gives more of the same, including a lump sum of 20 coins.

The tool tip implies that this can be used at the Mystic Forge in Lion's Arch, but doesn't say much more than that.

What combinations are the coins required for? I'm not looking for *every* recipe, but non-random recipes should have a "standard mixture", much like how crafting basic arms and armor is, for example, `Metal Chest Panel + Cloth Chest Padding + Insignia = new Chestpiece`.

I've heard that these coins can be used to receive crafting recipes, and also high-level weapons - what's the skinny there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To clarify what was outlined by Tapan Ze [above](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/81763/what-are-mystic-coins-used-for-and-what-are-zommoross-favorite-trades/82520#82520), mystic coins appear to be used exclusively in **Non-Random** mystic forge recipes.

The most pertinent (and eponymous) are the Mystic Weapons (of which there is one of each), which have the following recipe:

**Mystic Weapons**

- Tier 6 Weapon Component A (i.e., 5x Orichalcum Blade)
- Tier 6 Weapon Component B (i.e., 5x Orichalcum Hilt)
- 10 Mystic Coins
- 1 Eldritch Scroll (50 skill points to buy)

Which are each level 80 exotics of whichever weapon you put in.

[image]

There are a great deal more recipes for level 80 exotic items, and mystic coins play a large part in them (and in great sums, too!)

[This reddit thread has more](http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/zfr9x/mystic_forge_recipes_and_research_it_makes_exotics/) (and is the source of the picture, above).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the Wiki on the page [Mystic Forge](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Forge). It will tell you where the forge is, how it is used, and some predictable recipes. The forge lets you do two things. First you can create recipes to craft other items like consumables, weapons, or armor. Second, the forge can be used to create better crafting materials of one type higher.

The examples the wiki gives are as follows:

> **Common Crafting Material Promotion**
>
> Common crafting materials can be promoted to a small pile of higher
>   tier materials with the following formula. The tier of dust needed is equivalent to the tier of the wanted product. So, if you are hoping to create Orichalcum, a tier 6 common material, you need to use Crystalline Dust, a tier 6 dust. If common crafting material B is one tier higher than common crafting material A, then:
>
> 10-50 Crafting Material B = 250 Common Crafting Material A (i.e. 250 Mithril Ores) + 1 Common Crafting Material B (i.e. 1 Orichalcum Ores) + 2-5 Dust A (i.e. 5 Pile of  Crystalline Dust) + 5 Philosopher's stone

In that example: That recipe will produce 10-50 Orichalcum Ores

> **Armor boxes and armor satchels**
>
> Recipes can be created using the Mystic Forge. They will allow you to
>   craft armor boxes and armor satchels, which will in turn give you
>   every piece of an armor set.
>
> **Armor set recipe**
>
> Ingredients
>
> 5 Bottle of Elonian Wine
>
> 20 Arcane Crystal
>
> 50 Mystic Coin
>
> 1 Armor item

Mystic coins seem to be a common item needed for Food Trays, Weapons and Armor. Also look at [this page](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Mystic_Forge/Research) for current recipe research.

You can see this in action with this video on how to make a Giant Chocolate Cake. Details are in the video summary.